# Is there a hook that triggers when grant secondary user role in Wordpress?

Tags: hooks, user-roles

I know when change primary role, set_user_role will be triggered, is there a similar hook for grant secondary roles?

Comment: What do you mean by "secondary" role?

Answer (score 0):

If whatever is adding the second role is going through standard methods: [`WP_User::add_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_role/) then there's the [`add_user_role`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_user_role/) hook:

```
/**
 * Do something whenever a new role is added to an existing user
 * 
 * @param String $role
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse327081_add_uer_role( $role ) {

    // Do Things

}
add_action( 'add_user_role', 'wpse327081_add_uer_role', 10 );
```